# QGIS Atlas label not rendered using a Python expression: Eval Error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'QVariant'

Tags: qgis, qgis-atlas

In a QGIS atlas, I try to render a JSON field of features coming from a WFS3 vector layer using this Python expression:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import json

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_json_attribute(feature, parent):
    """
    get and render a specific json attribute from the attribute table
    """
    field_names = [field.name() for field in feature.fields()]
    d = dict(zip(field_names, feature.attributes())) 
    attribute_dict = json.loads(d['json_attribute']) 
    print(type(d['json_attribute'])) # prints: <class 'str'>
    print(type(attribute_dict)) # prints: <class 'dict'>

    # other stuff defining the results variable

    return results
```

But there seems to be an error at the line defining the `attribute_dict` variable:

```
Eval Error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'QVariant'
```

and the atlas is not rendering my object, simply the function's name (the "Preview" button is ON).

How to solve this?

The incoming `json_attribute` looks like:

```
{
"features":
  [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [7.432115, 48.187222],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "0",
      "properties": {
        "dist_square": 278,
        "name": ["PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. L'H.)"],
        "object_type": "classification name",
        "code": ["F104 natural ökol."],
        "geometry_type": 0
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },
    {...}, # each block is having the 
    {...}  # same structure.
  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

QGIS version 3.16.3-Hannover
Compiled against Qt 5.9.5

Comment: Can you share your JSON? Keep in mind, that `json.loads` takes a string as input and returns a dictionary as output; and `json.dumps` takes a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.

Comment: Yes, done. And the `d['json_attribute']` object I try to serialize is indeed a string. Also, if I copy paste the whole feature collection string in a standalone Python terminal, everything goes very well with `json.loads(the_whole_json_string)`.

Comment: QGIS 3.20 : looks ok and no QVariant involved. I don't know what do you do in the "other stuff" to get the `result` variable, but maybe you can get what you want with an expression like `array_foreach(map_get(from_json("json_attribute"), 'features'), map_get(@element, 'properties'))[0]` ?

Comment: I have to actually execute some nested loops to at least reach the second nested layer of the JSON object. And I was never able to figure out how to properly get properties out of that second level using 2 embedded `array_foreach()` functions as the `@element` always refers to the first loop. For example, your solution returns the properties as a dict or another JSON object, but I need to render them properly, line by line as "key: value" pairs, so I need to, again, loop over that dict to extract them all.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Follow-up: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416912/render-nested-part-of-a-json-object-in-a-qgis-atlas-label-each-property-on-its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't noticed, but when getting back to the "Insert expression" windows, the "Feature" field was automatically filled with a randomly wrong feature id:

[image: wrong feature id]

if I manually enter the feature id corresponding to the one I'd like to display, everything goes fine; the error disappears.

Fun fact: this feature id normally corresponds to a foreign key `fk_setup_id` which I actually used to filter the atlas so that I don't have to browse the more than 100'000 pages to figure out the feature I'm working on:

[image: custom filter on the atlas]

But the id used by the atlas to show pages doesn't seem to match the feature ids: so it's impossible to know the correspondence between the atlas pages and the features ids and one has to browse them all to find the right one, unless I missed something...

[image: atlas id doesn't match feature ids]
e.g. here, the number 1000 doesn't actually match the feature 1000.

Anyway, the original issue is solved.