# Render nested part of a JSON object in a QGIS Atlas label, each property on its own line of text

Tags: qgis, qgis-atlas

Follow up on this question: [QGIS Atlas label not rendered using a Python expression: Eval Error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'QVariant'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416909/qgis-atlas-label-not-rendered-using-a-python-expression-eval-error-the-json-ob) , how would you render the `properties` of the following JSON object, each on a separate line of text in a QGIS atlas?

```json
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
     "coordinates": [7.432115, 48.187222],
     "type": "Point"
   }, 
  "properties":
    { 
      "id": "0",
      "dist_square": 278,
      "name": ["PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. L'H.)"],
      "object_type": "classification name",
      "code": ["F104 natural ökol."],
      "geometry_type": 0
    }
}
```

From J. Monticolo's comment:

```sql
[%
  array_foreach(map_get(from_json("json_attribute"), 'features'),
    map_get(@element, 'properties'))[0]
%]
```

is resulting in only the first feature [0] (when it's a FeatureCollection, but I simplified the problem to a single feature here above):

```json
{
  "dist_square": 278,
  "name": ["PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. L'H.)"],
  "object_type": "classification name",
  "code": ["F104 natural ökol."],
  "geometry_type": 0
}
```

while this Python expression is giving correct results:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import json

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_json_attribute(feature, parent):
    results = ''
    field_names = [field.name() for field in feature.fields()]
    d = dict(zip(field_names, feature.attributes()))
    attributes = json.loads(d['json_attributes'])
    for i, feat in attributes.items():
        if i == 'properties':
            for k, v in feat.items():
                res_str = f"{k}: {v[0]}\n" if isinstance(v, list) else f"{k}: {v}\n"
                results += res_str

    return results
```

indeed, it results in:

> id: 0
> dist_square: 278
> name: PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. L'H.)
> object_type: classification name
> code: F104 natural ökol.
> geometry_type: 0

And this is what I've achieved so far in converting the previous Python expression using native QGIS functions but it results in an `Expression is invalid` error: `Eval Error: Field 'geometry_type:' not found`:

```sql
with_variable(
  'input_field',
  '{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "coordinates": [7.432115, 48.187222],
       "type": "Point"
     }, 
    "properties":
      { 
        "id": "0",
        "dist_square": 278,
        "name": ["PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. LH.)"],
        "object_type": "classification name",
        "code": ["F104 natural ökol."],
        "geometry_type": 0
      }
  }',
  array_foreach(
    map_get(from_json(@input_field), 'properties'),
    "id:" || map_get(@element, 'id') || '\n' ||
    "dist_square:" || map_get(@element, 'dist_square')  || '\n' ||
    "name:" || map_get(@element[0], 'name')  || '\n' ||
    "object_type:" || map_get(@element, 'object_type')  || '\n' ||
    "code:" || map_get(@element[0], 'code') || '\n' ||
    "geometry_type:" || map_get(@element, 'geometry_type') || '\n'
  )
)
```

And I'd like to avoid to hard code the name of the keys.

Is there any chance to get the same result with roughly the same amount of lines of code using native QGIS expression?

Answer (score 1):

The render order of the keys is not in the same as the original order in the JSON, it's alphabetical order.

But, here the QGIS expression :

```sql
with_variable(
  'json_attribute',
  '{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"coordinates": [7.432115, 48.187222], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {"id": "0", "dist_square": 278, "name": ["PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. LH.)"], "object_type": "classification name", "code": ["F104 natural ökol."], "geometry_type": 0}}',
with_variable(
  'properties',
  map_get(from_json(@json_attribute), 'properties'),
    array_to_string(
      array_foreach(
        map_akeys(@properties),
        format(
            '%1: %2',
            @element,
            CASE
              WHEN mime_type(map_get(@properties, @element)) = 'application/x-zerosize' THEN map_get(@properties, @element)[0]
              ELSE map_get(@properties, @element)
            END
        )
      )
  , '\n')
))
```

- `json_attribute` variable : the JSON
- `properties` variable : map (= Python dict) of the JSON properties
- `map_akeys` : list all map (= Python dict) keys
- for each keys (with `array_foreach`), format the array current `@element` and it's value. If the value is a list (mime_type = `application/x-zerosize`), so get the first value.

Result :

```
code: F104 natural ökol.
dist_square: 278
geometry_type: 0
id: 0
name: PCR_009 (St. Müst. ab. LH.)
object_type: classification name
```